# C# Serialization Surrogate - Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, serialization

I have an image class (VisionImage) that is a black box to me. I'm attempting to serialize the image object to file using Serialization Surrogates as explained on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188950.aspx). Below is my surrogate code.

```
sealed class VisionImageSerializationSurrogate : ISerializationSurrogate
{
    public void GetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        VisionImage image = (VisionImage)obj;
        byte[,] temp = image.ImageToArray().U8;
        info.AddValue("width", image.Width);
        info.AddValue("height", image.Height);
        info.AddValue("pixelvalues", temp, temp.GetType());
    }

    public Object SetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
    {
        VisionImage image = (VisionImage)obj;
        Int32 width = info.GetInt32("width");
        Int32 height = info.GetInt32("height");
        byte[,] temp = new byte[height, width];
        temp = (byte[,])info.GetValue("pixelvalues", temp.GetType());
        PixelValue2D tempPixels = new PixelValue2D(temp);
        image.ArrayToImage(tempPixels);
        return image;
    }
}
```

I've stepped through it to write to binary. It seems to be working fine (file is getting bigger as the images are captured). I tried to test it read the file back in. The values read back in are correct as far as the "info" object is concerned. When I get to the line

```
image.ArrayToImage(tempPixels);
```

It throws the "Cannot access a disposed object" exception. Upon further inspection, the object and the resulting image are both marked as disposed.

My code behind the form spawns an "acquisitionWorker" and runs the following code.

```
void acquisitionWorker_LoadImages(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //  This is the main function of the acquisition background worker thread.
        //  Perform image processing here instead of the UI thread to avoid a
        //  sluggish or unresponsive UI.
        BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
        try
        {
            uint bufferNumber = 0;
            //  Loop until we tell the thread to cancel or we get an error.  When this
            //  function completes the acquisitionWorker_RunWorkerCompleted method will
            //  be called.
            while (!worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                VisionImage savedImage = (VisionImage) formatter.Deserialize(fs);

                CommonAlgorithms.Copy(savedImage, imageViewer.Image);
                //  Update the UI by calling ReportProgress on the background worker.
                //  This will call the acquisition_ProgressChanged method in the UI
                //  thread, where it is safe to update UI elements.  Do not update UI
                //  elements directly in this thread as doing so could result in a
                //  deadlock.
                worker.ReportProgress(0, bufferNumber);
                bufferNumber++;
            }
        }
        catch (ImaqException ex)
        {
            //  If an error occurs and the background worker thread is not being
            //  cancelled, then pass the exception along in the result so that
            //  it can be handled in the acquisition_RunWorkerCompleted method.
            if (!worker.CancellationPending)
                e.Result = ex;
        }
    }
```

What am I missing here? Why would the object be immediately disposed?